# What is the exact use-case for ContinueAsNew

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow, uber-cadence

Team,

What is the exact use case to use continueAsNew?

As we have support for CronSchedule to do periodic activities, I don't know the scenario to use this.

Are we having this to give backward compatibility

Answer (score 2):

There are many scenarios besides cron that require always running workflows. For example, a workflow that listens for external events and keeps some aggregated state. Such workflow will eventually run out of the history size limit. To support such workflow processing an unlimited number of events, it has to call continue as new periodically.

Comment: Thanks for the response